# Microsoft CRM 2016

Tags: dynamic, plugins, crm

I using Microsoft Dynamic CRM, On the top of CRM Index page( navigation bar).

I would like customize the navigation bar adding a "new button" as I mentioned below picture. Is this possible to change main page ? Let me know how to achieve.

Note:
I tried with sitemap customization , I able to  creating Button or short cut  in Area and Sub-Area. Is it possible by create icon placing near to nav bar ? any alternative ideas?
(for example)

[Refer the Attached Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4PU1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible in a supported way.

Comment: Or Is it possible to Develop a Sliding panel which attached in main CRM Page provided  (example) http://amatyran.com/codecanyon/sticklr/ if so How ?

Comment: Again that probably wouldn't be supported. At the end of the day you can write JavaScript to do anything in CRM, i.e. interact with the DOM to add buttons or whatever, or even go crazy and edit the CRM files directly. But as that's not supported it may break when CRM is upgraded. Typically I would avoid unsupported customisations, but its up to you. Suggested reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350.aspx